# Upgrading from t2.micro to m3.large without losing data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, cloud

I have an amazon t2.micro instance running RHEL7. I want to upgrade the instance type from t2.micro to an m3 large instance. I want to use the same drive for the m3 large instance as I have all the software installed there.

From this page http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ I find that m3.large uses SSD storage and t2.micro uses EBS storage. Is there some way to clone the drive in EBS connected to t2.mirco so that I can use the exact same data on an m3 large instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage types on the page referred to are just the default for "instance storage" (i.e. any ephemeral storage) when an instance is launched.

If you upgrade the size of the instance, the boot partition (where your data is currently stored) and any other EBS volumes you have attached yourself will remain the same as they are now.

This does ***not*** apply to ephemeral storage volumes however. These are only provided for temporary storage and won't survive an instance being terminated or resized. The T2 instance types don't have any ephemeral volumes anyway so this is not an issue in this case.

Take a snapshot of volumes you care about before the upgrade if you are concerned, but I have switched instance types many times without any issues.